# JSP lint/validator tool

Tags: compiler, validation, lint

I’m looking for a static code analyzer that will check the syntax of our Java Server Pages code.  We’re migrating to Tomcat 9 that is stricter and throwing errors for things like “Attribute qualified names must be unique within an element” and “The JSP specification requires that an attribute name is preceded by whitespace”.  I’d like to validate the code without having to do a full regression test.